# Saving many persistents configurations values with javascript

Tags: javascript, web-storage

I have many  `dropdown lists` which I created and work properly .When I click on its `list title` element (here on City ) it `opens` or shows  its dropdown menu below .
Below is an illustration to let you know  how all my dropdown list are made .

```
<div class="dropdown-container">
 <div class="title">City </div> 
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
   <li class="glist_item">Calgary</li>
   <li class="glist_item">Miisssauga</li>
   <li class="glist_item">Winnipeg</li>
   <li class="glist_item">Vancouver</li>
   <li class="glist_item">Surrey</li>
 </ul> 
</div>
```

My problem is how to save the state (`opened` or `closed`)  of each  dropdown list  after the page reloads so  that those who were opened or closed  keep their respectives state before reload.

NB: I tried `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` before but these cannot store `complex data` or data with many records since the number of list is undefined .

So I need  a persistent data storage capability as well as an ability to store data like **array** does .
CAN  YOU HELP ME ?

Comment: Can you show us how you use the `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`?

Comment: I don' t have problem using localStorage . The issue is to store data in this storage like array does . May be to achieve ,  by using localStorage  before setting value  I should convert array into string type with JSON.stringify method  and later into Array .@ThumChoonTat

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding your question, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values) answer your question?

Comment: LocalStorage can deal with complex data, you just need to serialize it properly. A json object can be serialized to a string by `JSON.stringify()`. Then it can be revived back to json object by `JSON.parse` simple as that.

Comment: Thanks this is what I am about to do @hackape

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way. Just create an array includes information of lists states.

```
let states = {
  list1: "opened",
  list2: "opened",
  list3: "closed",
  list4: "opened",
  list5: "opened",
}
```

Here, I think you can change listx to list id.

You can save this to `localStorage` by converting it to string.
Then, you can get that string from `localStorage` and parse it to js object and do what you are going to do.